# Maven versioning strategy

Tags: git, maven

Question from a Linux System admin trying to understand Maven & Git versioning strategy.

In my team Git branching is like: Master, Develop and multiple feature branches as per the requirement.

Say, multiple teams working parallely on their feature branches, once a stable phase has arrived, PR requests are raised to merge to the Develop branch.

How should versioning be handled in latest and greatest fashion in this case?  Its a multi module maven project, so the version increment has to be applied to all the POMs recursively and in the dependencies section as well ?
I'm really confused how maven will sort out or identify the increment in the numbers while resolving dependencies.

P.S : I had went thru the official documentation of Maven and Git and studied multiple blogs before posting this and came across maven relase plugin , CI friendly plugin but I felt those didnt answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a multi-module project you set the new version through

`mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2.3`

This will set the version in all POMs.

Dependencies between modules of the multi-module project should always be declared with the version `${project.version}` so that they get replaced automatically.